# Как вывести XML или DataSet в ASP.NET MVC 3 ?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Собственно, как вывести XML на вьюху в виде таблицы? Или же есть вариант вывода информации из объекта System.Data.DataSet.
Загвоздка в том, что количество столбцов и строк динамическое и каждый раз разное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML-документ, как известно, имеет древовидную структуру. Поэтому таблица здесь не самый удачный выбор - у вас может быть крайне неравномерное распределение данных внутри этой таблицы. Деревья обычно  обходятся с помощью рекурсии, поэтому вам нужен  а) некий алгоритм для получения информации из вашего XML-документа.  б) весьма желательно  отказаться от табличного представления в пользу древовидных  контролов.

По поводу алгоритма обхода - он может быть как [рекурсивным](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144850/), так и [нерекурсивным](http://www.lardite.com/2011/10/blog-post.html)
Что касается контролов, то я бы рекомендовал использовать [что-нибудь готовое](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview). Впрочем, конечно, можете попробовать с таблицами, но скорее всего получится что-то страшное

Comment: @DreamChild, а если из объекта DataSet?

Comment: что из объекта DataSet?

Comment: @DreamChild, я обновил вопрос. Что если выводить не из XML, а из объекта DataSet ? (есть такая возможность)

Comment: @Jembo_by  я не очень понимаю, что вы хотите. Вам нужно вывести данные на представление? Тогда не имеет значения, откуда вы их выводите  - исходя из принципа MVC ваше представление не должно знать, как и откуда вы берете данные. Если  же вас волнует вопрос, как выводить данные из DataSet'a, то нужно помнить, что DataSet содержит в себе объекты DataTable, следовательно, вам нужно выбрать таблицу из DataSet'a, а из данных,  хранящихся в таблице, заполнять модель. Думаю, проблем с получением данных из таблицы быть не должно

Comment: @DreamChild, спасибо, завтра попробую и отпишусь или отмечу ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
@{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    doc.Load("stream/string/т.д.);
}

<table>
<tbody>
@foreach(var elem in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    //бегаем циклом по иерархии, соответственно, может быть N циклов, количество вытащите из doc
    <tr>  
    <td>
        @elem."свойство"
    </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Макс Жуков, извините, но это чепуха

Comment: @DreamChild, аргументируйте, плз.

Comment: @Макс Жуков XML древовиден. Здесь нужна рекурсия, так как вы не можете заранее знать, сколько циклов вам понадобится. Существуют, конечно, и нерекурсивные методы обхода, в том числе и с foreach'ами, но это  несколько не то, что вы представили

Comment: @DreamChild, согласен, Вы правы.

Comment: @Макс Жуков, а если из объекта DataSet?

Comment: @DreamChild, я обновил вопрос